# How can you make an algorithm to only search once for each input?

Tags: reactjs

So i have a program that fetches an API which contains a list of foods. And whenever a person searches for a word, the foods get displayed in the client side. But the problem is that if someone enters for example the breakfast, it should only render under the breakfast section and when someone enters the lunch, it should render all the data under lunch. But as for now, it renders everything altogether, so when I input something in breakfast, it also gets rendered in lunch.

I've tried creating two states so that it renders first in one and then in another, but that's not working as it also renders together.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

function DietForm() {
    const [result, setResult] = useState('')
    const [result2, setResult2] = useState('')
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
    const [message, setMessage] = useState('')
    const [data, setData] = useState([])
    const [data2, setData2] = useState([])


    const handleOnInputChange = (e) => {
      setResult(e.target.value)
   }


   const handleOnInputChange2 = (e) => {
     setResult2(e.target.value)
   }
    
    useEffect(() => {
      const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://edamam-food-and-grocery-database.p.rapidapi.com/parser',
        params: {ingr: result},
        headers: {
          'x-rapidapi-host': 'edamam-food-and-grocery-database.p.rapidapi.com',
          'x-rapidapi-key': '6bc4948226msh1716c54bf80ad8dp1c8c12jsnac7a17a9e0a6'
        }
      };
      console.log(options.params.ingr)
      axios.request(options).then(function (response) {
          setData(response.data);
          setData2(response.data)
          console.log(response.data)
      }).catch(function (error) {
          console.error(error);
      });
    
    }, [result])
    
    console.log(result)
    return (
        <div>
            <form class="w-full max-w-lg">
  <div class="flex flex-wrap -mx-3 mb-6">
    <div class="w-full md:w-1/2 px-3 mb-6 md:mb-0">
      <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2" for="grid-first-name">
        Breakfast
      </label>
      <input value={result} class="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-red-500 rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white" id="grid-first-name" type="text" onChange={handleOnInputChange} placeholder="Search" />
      {data?.hints?.map((data) => <div key={data.id}>{data.food.label} 
      <button>Add</button>
      </div>) || 'No results found'}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex flex-wrap -mx-3 mb-6">
  <div class="w-full md:w-1/2 px-3">
      <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2" onChange={handleOnInputChange2} for="grid-last-name">
        Lunch
      </label>
      <input class="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-gray-200 rounded py-3 px-4 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500" id="grid-last-name" type="text" onChange={handleOnInputChange2} placeholder="Search" />
      {data2?.hints?.map((data) => <div key={data.id}>{data.food.label} 
      <button>Add</button>
      </div>) || 'No results found'}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex flex-wrap -mx-3 mb-2">
  <div class="w-full md:w-1/2 px-3">
      <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2" for="grid-last-name">
        Dinner
      </label>
      <input class="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-gray-200 rounded py-3 px-4 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500" id="grid-last-name" type="text" placeholder="Search" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex flex-wrap -mx-3 mb-2">
  <div class="w-full md:w-1/2 px-3">
      <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2" for="grid-last-name">
        Snack
      </label>
      <input class="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-gray-200 rounded py-3 px-4 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500" id="grid-last-name" type="text" placeholder="Search" />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default DietForm
```